# Trying to validate column with formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation-list-items

I have text field called `ID Proyecto` into list and I want to add column validation to accept no more than 6 digits so into Column Validation I add:

```
=LEN(ID Proyecto) < 7
```

But I get

> Formula contains an error or sintaxis are wrong

I also try

```
=IF(LEN(ID Proyecto) < 7,TRUE,FALSE)
```

But same result. What am I doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the "ID Proyecto" does not contain Space, like this format:

785566.

Then you can edit this “ID Proyecto" column in list settings and set "6" for the "Maximum number of characters" option.

[image]